# IONIC 2 Range slider initial position

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've tried to look around the web for a long time in order to solve this problem, basically I have a range slider and I'm trying to set its default starting values but with no succes, neither in the official documentation nor around the web I was able to find anything, what is the correct way? I'm able to get and display the actual value of the range in this way:

**home.html**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-range [(ngModel)]="rangeSettings" (ionChange)="cValue($event, 'slider1')">
      <ion-icon range-left small name="water"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon range-right name="water"></ion-icon>
    </ion-range>
  </ion-item>
  Flusso d'acqua
  <ion-badge color="secondary">{{slideValueBadge[slideValueBadge.length -1]}}</ion-badge>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  socket:any
  chat_input:string;
  chats = [];
  prova = [];
  rangeSettings:any;
  slideValueBadge = [];


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
   var a;
   this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

   this.rangeSettings = {
       type: "double",
       min: 0,
       max: 1000,
       from: 200,
       to: 500
   };


   this.socket.on('message', (msg) => {
     console.log("message", msg);
     this.chats.push(msg);
   });

   this.socket.on('prova', (msgProva) => {
       console.log("msgProva", msgProva);
       this.prova.push(msgProva);
   });

   this.socket.on('sValue', (value) => {
       this.slideValueBadge.push(value);
       console.log("sliderValue:", value);
   });
  }

  send(msg) {
        if(msg != ''){
            this.socket.emit('message', msg);
        }
        this.chat_input = '';
  }
  cValue(event, nome) {
      console.log("SliderValue", event._valA);
      this.socket.emit('sValue', event._valA);
  }
}
```

So how can I set the default starting position of the slider to, for example, 20?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make the value of the range `[(ngModel)]` of type object, just change it to
  `rangeSettings: number = 20;`

and you can set the option of directly from the html

```
<ion-range dualKnobs="true" min="0" max="1000" step="2" [(ngModel)]="rangeSettings">
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to put properties in `[(ngModel)]`. `[(ngModel)]` is to bind (2 way binding in `[(ngModel)]` this case) a propert to UI. I am sure if you use it correctly, you can set the default value.

E.g. like this:

In `.html`

```
<ion-range [(ngModel)]="myValue" (ionChange)="cValue($event, 'slider1')">
```

In `.ts`:

```
myValue = 20;
```

If you want to set the properties in `rangeSettings` to `<ion-range>` then apply it separately like this:

```
<ion-range min="0" max="1000" [(ngModel)]="myValue" (ionChange)="cValue($event, 'slider1')"></ion-range>
```